# Google play READ_CALL_LOG permission

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

Reading call log is the basic feature of my app, but i dont know which option to select among the following in the list in the declaration form.

```
Default SMS handler

Default Phone handler

Default Assistant handler

Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

Enterprise archive, CRM, and device management

Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking

Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)

Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls

SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)

SMS based money management

Proxy calls

Services - Carrier

Services - OEM

Device Automation

Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)

Call-based OTP account verification

Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)

Write and Show Call History in Dialer

In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display

Anti-SMS Phishing
```

Since its only write and show call history in dialer option thats close to my requirement, i selected this, but now i got thefollowing email from google.

Google Play
Developer update

> Hi Developers at Bot Entity, Thanks for contacting the Google Play
> team about your app Whatsupp Direct, com.whatsappdirect.wd. Publishing
> Status     Publishing status: Rejected After review, your app has been
> rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you
> submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still
> available on Google Play. Issue: Violation of Permissions policy After
> reviewing your app, we found that it doesn’t qualify to use the
> requested permissions for the following reason(s): App is using
> unnecessary permissions When you submitted your app, you specified
> your app's core functionality as follows: Write and Show Call History
> in Dialer. However, based on the permitted uses, your app is only
> allowed to access the following permissions: WRITE_CALL_LOG. Please
> remove the following permission(s) from your app: READ_CALL_LOG.

now how do i get READ_CALL_LOG in the list??